# Watson Studio Error While Trying To Create Free Service

Tags: ibm-watson, edx, watson-discovery

The resource group 54d2a150a7774f38b20612e19f71cafa is inactive with state: SUSPENDED Open a support case and include the resource group name in the case details.

Transaction ID: b423473afc8044f79baf962d4d140081

I get the error above when trying to access WATSON studio. I am currently studying online on EDX to acquire knowledge to become a Data Scientist.

I tried creating a free service by following the step by step guide shown on edx portal.

All steps were followed correctly but the error kept popping up after many attempts.

Comment: I believe you could share your feedback in the Forum section of the course, and about the resource group that inactive, maybe talk to the Watson support team?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.